# mu4e does not sync the "move to folder" action to the IMAP server

Tags: spacemacs, email, mu4e, imap

I am using spacemacs (I don't think it should matter though) mu/mu4e and mbsync

When I use "move to folder" followed by "execute mark", I expect the "movement of message from Inbox to Archive" to be reflected on the IMAP server. **But it doesn't** :(

The message is "moved" from mu4e interface (I think that means mbsync locally considers the message moved) but this is not reflected on the server.

If I use `(setq mu4e-change-filenames-when-moving t)` in my `.spacemacs` there is an *appearance* of the movement (i.e. Message appears in the `Archive` folder, but it is a **copy**. i.e. Message is still in the `Inbox` and the *move* created a copy into the `Archive` folder. I definitely **don't** want that. So I have commented the above config setting.

I am not even sure whether this is supported.

If yes, how do I fix this ? Pointer to documentation/URL should be OK too.

Thanks.

---

Edit: Additional info, part of my `.mbsyncrc`

```
# Automatically create missing mailboxes, both locally and on the server
Create Both
# Save the synchronization state files in the relevant directory
SyncState *
```

I am not using gmail. I'm using [Zoho IMAP server](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/imap-access.html), if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize I am answering my own question. But leaving it here so that it is helpful for someone in the future.

---

It turns out it was a quirk with the IMAP server I was using. (URL in the question)

I had to turn on "Expunge immediately" option in the Server settings for the changes from mu4e to reflect on the server.